# Date4j compare 2 times

Tags: java, datetime

So, it's my understanding that Date4J (http://www.date4j.net/javadoc/hirondelle/date4j/DateTime.html) is a little bit easier to use than JodaTime so I've been using it in one of my projects.  It's working out well, but I'm trying to create a last seen function for the last time an event took place.  I have 2 objects, lastOnline and now.  Their values are as follows:

```
LastOnline year 2015---Now.year--2015
LastOnline Month 1---Now.Month--1
LastOnline Day 18---Now.Day--18
LastOnline Hour 14---Now.Hour--14
LastOnline Minute 13---Now.Minute--33
LastOnline Second 24---Now.Second--15
LastOnline NanoSecond 1421590404000---Now.Nanosecond--1421591595316
```

I got that with the following commands:

```
    System.out.println("LastOnline year " + lastOnline.getYear() + "---Now.year--" + now.getYear());
    System.out.println("LastOnline Month " + lastOnline.getMonth() + "---Now.Month--" + now.getMonth());
    System.out.println("LastOnline Day " + lastOnline.getDay() + "---Now.Day--" + now.getDay());
    System.out.println("LastOnline Hour " + lastOnline.getHour() + "---Now.Hour--" + now.getHour());
    System.out.println("LastOnline Minute " + lastOnline.getMinute() + "---Now.Minute--" + now.getMinute());
    System.out.println("LastOnline Second " + lastOnline.getSecond() + "---Now.Second--" + now.getSecond());
    System.out.println("LastOnline NanoSecond " + lastOnline.getMilliseconds(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")) + "---Now.Nanosecond--" + now.getMilliseconds(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));
```

With that said, I took a look at the documentation for the .minus function and I can't seem to get it to work, it's throwing a ton of NullPointerExceptions and I can't seem to figure out why.  Here is my minus function:

```
DateTime difference;
difference = now.minus(lastOnline.getYear(), lastOnline.getMonth(), lastOnline.getDay(), lastOnline.getHour(), 
lastOnline.getMinute(), lastOnline.getSecond(), lastOnline.getNanoseconds(), DateTime.DayOverflow.FirstDay);
```

And lastly here's a stack trace--

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at hirondelle.date4j.DateTime.minus(Unknown Source)
at globalFunctions.compareTime(globalFunctions.java:177)
at globalFunctions.logScrape(globalFunctions.java:158)
at Commands.bangCommands(Commands.java:32)
at Commands.handleCommands(Commands.java:9)
at listener.main(listener.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: I don't understand your "nanosecond"-value of 1421591595316. According to the documentation the valid value range is 0-999,999,999

Comment: Ah I see, you get it via the method `getMilliseconds()`, but this is NOT the nanosecond value. It is the count of elapsed milliseconds since Unix epoch.

Comment: Right, sorry about that,  I mislabeled it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
DateTime now = DateTime.forInstant(1421591595316L, tz);
DateTime lastOnline = DateTime.forInstant(1421590404000L, tz);
        
DateTime difference = 
  now.minus(lastOnline.getYear(), lastOnline.getMonth(),
            lastOnline.getDay(), lastOnline.getHour(),
            lastOnline.getMinute(), lastOnline.getSecond(), 
            lastOnline.getNanoseconds(), DateTime.DayOverflow.FirstDay);
```

With exact your input values based on your milliseconds-since-epoch-data (which you have mislabelled as nanosecond parts) I don't get an NPE, but this:

**Exception in thread "main" hirondelle.date4j.DateTime$ItemOutOfRange: Year is not in the range 1..9999. Value is:-1.**

For me, I would rather have expected the **difference of zero years** instead of `-1` (which is also out of supported range). Probably a bug. This suspicion is almost certainty after I had tested the expression `lastOnline.minus(lastOnline.getYear(), ...)`. **The behaviour remains unchanged even if both operands are the same.** However, if I set the nanosecond part to `null` then I really get an NPE:

```
    DateTime lastOnline = new DateTime(2015, 1, 18, 14, 13, 24, null);
    DateTime now = new DateTime(2015, 1, 18, 14, 33, 15, null);
```

**Important side note: Do you try to calculate a difference? But a `DateTime`-object is a point in time, not a difference.**

Date4J does not have the concept of a duration meaning there is no object model representing a duration, also no concept of different handling of fields and units (which results in a very poor and narrow set of supported fields). So you tried to calculate the difference between two `DateTime` objects by using the fields of the second arg as units and then representing the resulting duration as new `DateTime' object (which cannot process zero durations in years, months and days due to range constraints regarding your input data).

The only somehow useable methods of Date4J to calculate durations are obviously:

[numDaysFrom](http://www.date4j.net/javadoc/hirondelle/date4j/DateTime.html#numDaysFrom%28hirondelle.date4j.DateTime%29)

[numSecondsFrom](http://www.date4j.net/javadoc/hirondelle/date4j/DateTime.html#numSecondsFrom%28hirondelle.date4j.DateTime%29)

=> My recommendation: Date4J does not handle calculations of durations well so you should try to **use a library capable of calculating durations spanning from years to fractional seconds**. Actually I know two libs doing this (Joda-Time and my own library - both can also format durations).

If the new java-time-package in Java-8 is interesting for you then consider that it cannot do this surprisingly, only calculate durations in either years-months-days (class `Period` or hours-minutes-seconds-nanos (class `Duration`) but not mixed. Maybe you can elaborate a workaround using a combination of both classes in a multi-unit-time-delta-class.